Reference request: Stochastic calculus on manifolds
As mentioned in the title, I am looking for a book or lecture notes on stochastic calculus on manifolds.
Background: I have completed reading Brownian Motion, Stochastic Calculus by Le Gall. Additionally, I have taken a course in differentiable manifolds and explored books such as An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring Tu and Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John Lee.
I have also reviewed Stochastic Analysis on Manifolds by Elton Hsu, but I find it too advanced for my current level. Therefore, I am seeking a book or resource that is more accessible to a master's student.
Lastly, what fundamental theories or concepts should I be familiar with to effectively study stochastic calculus on manifolds?
Thank you in advance!

David Elworthy, Stochastic Differential Equations on Manifolds. 40 or so years old now but may be more readable and 'intuitive' for that reason
